# Subsetting data into percentage groups

Tags: r, subset

I have about 9k observations for 2 variables for which I want to test for correlation. I was initially subsetting this by value, which I had no issues with. I realised that I wouldnt get a statistically significant correlation for some value groups due to low observation count. I have decided to change my approach to group by quantiles. I can currently subset the top X% with no trouble, but am having difficulty figuring out how to group all data into multiple percentiles i.e 0-5%, 5-10%, 10-15%. Help much appreciated. Thanks, Jono

Comment: Can try `cut(x, quantile(x, seq(0,1, 0.05)))` and by the way, are you trying to subset the data by values of a third variable or one among the two?

Comment: I am trying to subset by the values of one of the 2 variables, but I want to retain the other related variable.

Comment: I get the same results as I have mentioned in the comment below. I am not looking to return the quantile end points and frequency, but the values for both variables. So I am basically trying to split one table into 20 based on the value of one variable. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

We can use  `cut2` function in `Hmisc` package

```
library(Hmisc)
cut2(x, g=20)
```

It divides your data into 20 quantiles as you wish

Comment: So this returns me the end points of the quantiles for that variable, and the frequency of observations in that quantile. As per the below:

Comment: Var1 Freq
1 [-56.3423,-4.2891) 21
2 [ -4.2891,-2.0039) 21
3 [ -2.0039,-1.2219) 21
4 [ -1.2219,-0.6693) 21
5 [ -0.6693,-0.0328) 21
6 [ -0.0328, 0.5287) 21
7 [  0.5287, 0.9879) 21
What I am trying to achieve is to split the 1 table into 20 tables with the values of both variables for each 5% quantile. I hope I am making sense, this is my first post on S.O. Thanks for your response

Comment: you can add a column that shows the quntile and then use subset. `library(dplyr) temp$quartile <- ntile(temp$value, 4)` please let me know if it works for you

Comment: @MFR are you suggesting one more alternative to do it?